# Macro functions const parameter

Tags: c++, c, macros, constants

I define:

```
#define macroFunction(A,...)    function((uint8_t*) A)
```

And then

```
void function(const uint8_t*A){
    #do Something
}
```

Is this OK? or is there a way to "tell" the macro to only accept `const`s ?

-> This compiles and works, I'm wondering if it's a good practice.

-> yes, the use of macros is neccesary, I'm showing a simplfied example.

Thanks!

Comment: not quite clear how the macro relates to the function definition. The macro is neither a call (it has the parameter type) nor a declaration (no return type). What is it?

Comment: When an `int` is passed by value, qualifying it as `const` makes no difference whatsoever to the caller.   For `const` to be meaningful, the argument needs to be either a pointer or a reference.      And, no, use of macros is very rarely necessary - the only realworld cases where it is of use is if using include guards or macros that are predefined by the standard.       In any event, your post reads like an XY-problem - which means you have decided the solution to some problem is a macro but others would disagree - if they only knew about your ACTUAL problem.

Comment: @idclev463035818 I think I corrected it, sorry, i'm still trying to understand :)

Comment: @Ivan you changed  `par1` to `A`, but I still don't understand what that macro should be good for. You can't use it to call the function and you cant use it to declare the function, what is it for?

Comment: @Peter you are right, it's part of a standard :)  and in our the argument is indeed a pointer (unit_t*) , I chose *any* type when wrtiing the question

Comment: @idclev463035818 it's meant to call the function

Comment: eg `macroFunction(x)` will expand to `function(int x)`, as the answer says, thats not very useful. I suggest you to stay away from macros. No matter how much you are convinced that you have a good case for macros, I am certain that you don't

Comment: why do you want to cast to a non-const `uint8_t*` and then require that it must be `const` ?!? This is indeed a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: State what the actual goal is. Are you attempting to ensure the argument passed to the function **is** a constant or that it **points to** a `const`-qualified type? Or something else? We cannot know if some pieces of code are good for their purpose unless we know what their purpose is.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> #define macroFunction(par1,...)    function(int A)
> ```
>
> Is this OK?

No, I don't see any case where that would be useful.

> is there a way to "tell" the macro to only accept consts ?

No.

> ```
> void function(const int A){
> ```

Even for a proper function, there is no difference in what can be passed into a function accepting const, or function accepting non-const parameter. The only difference between those is that the function cannot modify the const variable. Given that functions should preferably be kept short and simple, constness of parameters is rarely very useful.